# Apache mod_rewrite not working properly on Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard)

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a PHP website with clean URLs with Apache's mod_rewrite, using a .htaccess file.  mod_rewrite seems to be working, however, it claims it cannot find files on my server that do exist.

Just as a basic test, this is what my .htaccess file looks like at the moment--going to [mysite]/page should redirect to the index.php file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^page$ index.php
```

Afaik, I have setup the .conf file appropriately as well:

```
<Directory "/Users/myuser/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

However, when I try accessing the URL setup via mod_rewrite ( localhost/~myuser/mysite/page ), I get this:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /Users/myuser/Sites/mysite/index.php was not found on this server.
```

However, that file does exist, and that is the proper location!  The site works fine otherwise, if I go to localhost/~myuser/mysite/index.php, everything works fine--minus any sort of clean URLs, of course.

Has anyone seen this before/have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does your Apache ErrorLog say?  And when you turn on RewriteLog, does it show you what you think it should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need RewriteBase if you're in your userdir and substituting to a relative path.

Comment: Read the docs for RewriteBase and turned out to be exactly what I needed--thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to add FollowSymlinks after Multiviews. I wrote a tutorial for the whole thing here:

http://www.jermexpress.com/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-on-snow-leopard-10-6/

Hope that solves your problem. Cheers! :)